# Throw error from custom resource function not resulting in stack creation failure

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript, aws-cdk-custom-resource

I am implementing a custom resource in CDK. In the success scenario all works well. The CDK stack is deployed and the custom resource calls the Lambda function it should invoke using the construct [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html). The stack deployed to the account finishes in a success state. I can also affirm that the function ran correctly as the log shows `this.account` printed from the event object. However when I throw an error in the function called by [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html), I would expect it stack creation to fail. However it still succeeds.

The body of the function called by the [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) is:

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {

    console.log(event);

    return new Error("ERROR FROM REMOTE FUNCTION");

};
```

I also tried:

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {

    console.log(event);

    throw new Error("ERROR FROM REMOTE FUNCTION");

};
```

My implementation of [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) in the stack is (please note the the function is first deployed and then called by the functions ARN):

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { custom_resources as cr } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { aws_iam as iam } from "aws-cdk-lib";

export class Test extends cdk.Stack {

  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const crRole = new iam.Role(this, 'MyRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole')
      ]
    });

    const myCustomResource = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'MyCustomResource', {
      onUpdate: {
        service: 'Lambda',
        action: 'invoke',
        parameters: {
          FunctionName: 'ARN_TO_THE_FUNCTION',
          Payload: JSON.stringify({
            account: this.account
          })
        },
        physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
      },
      role: crRole,
    });

  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

`AwsCustomResource` is a custom resource that calls an AWS API. In your case, its only task is to invoke a lambda - and it does that successfully. Your lambda is not part of the custom resource.

To make a lambda-backed custom resource, use the [`Provider`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.Provider.html) construct.

Here is an example from the docs:

```js
declare const onEvent: lambda.Function;
declare const isComplete: lambda.Function;
declare const myRole: iam.Role;
const myProvider = new cr.Provider(this, 'MyProvider', {
  onEventHandler: onEvent,
  isCompleteHandler: isComplete,
  logRetention: logs.RetentionDays.ONE_DAY,
  role: myRole,
  providerFunctionName: 'the-lambda-name',   // Optional
});
```

Your function will have to handle different event payloads, such as Create/Update/Delete, return the physical ID, etc.